# Method to insert an array or dictionary into db database in Google App Engine - Python

Tags: python, json, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to Python (and OOP) and working on a challenging project (and first post here!). I tried searching, but could not find anything of use, or perhaps did not know what to search for.

Here is what I want to do:

I have two tables in db (from google.appengine.ext).  One is "fruits" with name of fruits and their nutrition info and the other is "user" which I want to store two columns, uid and favFruits (fruits they like, their score (5-star scale) and a comment).  Problem I am having is each user (uid row) can have multiple fruits they like and comment.  The favFruits will be shown on user's profile and when the link is clicked, it goes to nutrition page.

Example:

```
"favFruits":[
   {
    "fruit":"fuji apple"
    "score":"4"
    "comment":"Delicious. Bit tart, but very sweet"
   },
   {
    "fruit":"orange"
    "score":"5"
    "comment":"I just love it!"
   }
 ]
```

What would be the best method to store this in the Google Appengine Datastore?  Currently I am using db.StringListProperty() with only favFruits['fruit'] as the list input, which does not include ['score'] or ['comment'].  What I really want is to store 2D table inside a column (an array into a column of db) that is efficiently search-able, as soon as uid is identified.

Is Json the best approach?  What about concatenating into a single string containing all three fields into a string and store the list (like [u'orange,5,I just love it!']?

If there is a better approach, please let me know!  I am stuck... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first advise: use NDB. Using NDB you have structured and JSON properties, built-in caching and much more: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

You can use an NDB structured repeated property for favFruits.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured

A JSON property (a blob) cannot be used in a query.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I am in the process of switching from db to NDB and will use structured property.  I am stuck with some of the syntax of NDB however, since it is different from db.. I will post another question shortly on this.  Thanks again!